# Create subset of php array and convert to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is one of those that should be easy.  I'm not even sure if "subset" is the right way to describe it.

My initial array looks like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["claim_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(2) "50" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 01:58:48" ["created"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 01:58:48" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["claim_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(2) "45" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 03:34:59" ["created"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 03:37:01" } [2]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" ["claim_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(2) "50" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 22:47:46" ["created"]=> string(19) "2013-05-15 22:52:02" } }
```

I'd ultimately like to end up with just the date and price values, swap them so that date is first in the array, reformat the date, and convert it to a json array that looks something like this:

```
[{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"50"},{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"45"},{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"50"}]
```

I ran a foreach statement to get at the data and reformat the date, then went out of my league with splice, unset, and other functions that took me in the wrong direction.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$array = array();
for($i = 0 ; $i<count($your_array);$i++) {
     $a=array();
     $a['date'] = $your_array[$i]['date'];
     $a['price'] = date("F .j",strtotime($your_array[$i]["date"]));
     array_push($array,$a);
}

json_encode($array);
```

## Output

```
[{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"50"},{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"45"},{"date":"Mar. 15","price":"50"}]
```

## Codepad

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on this line (am not sure why-- it looks correct to me):  `$a['date'] = date("F .j",strtotime($your_array[$i]["date"]);`

Comment: @dilettante I forgot one closing `)` in this line.Now fixed.

Comment: Gah. I should have seen that. Thanks for catching. This works brilliantly; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there

```
$ret = array();
foreach ($source as $rec){
     $ret[] = array("date"=>$rec["date"], "price"=>$rec["price"]);
}
$json = json_encode($ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconstruct array using correct foreach  and the use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get the json

```
 $req_array = array();
 foreach($youArray as $value)
 {
   $temp = array();
   $temp['date']   = $value['date'];
   $temp['price']  = $value['price'];
   $req_array[]     = $temp;
}

$json = json_encode($req_array);
echo $json;
```

see [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a3k-qb1)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
 $infos =array(
           array("id" =>"1","price"=>"50","date"=>"2013-05-15 01:58:48"),
           array("id" =>"2","price"=>"55","date"=>"2013-06-15 01:58:48")
         );
 $i=0;
 foreach ($infos as $info )   
 {
    $infos[$i]["date"]= date("F .j",strtotime($info["date"]));
    $i++;
 }

 echo json_encode($infos);
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to spit out the original json-encoded array, though?

Answer (score 0):

Create a quick function to create another array with only selected elements:

```
function datePriceToJson($array) {
   $a = array();
   foreach($array as $i => $a) {
      $a[] = array("date" => $a['date'], "price" => $a['price']); //Creae a new array based on the one you want
   }
   return json_encode($a);
}

datePriceToJson($array);
```